# Campaign set as (not set) with Firebase and AdWords

Tags: swift, firebase, google-analytics, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

I have connected my AdWords account to Firebase and I'm using Firebase Analytics in the iOS SDK for Swift 3 to track events, however, the campaign name is (not set) rather than anything specific, so I can't gain insight into how my specific event is doing. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You should probably contact Firebase support about this.  What you have now isn't a programming question.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Please contact Firebase support with your information so they can take a deeper look into the issue. We don't have enough information on StackOverflow to answer your question.